# React: When Does Context Provider Update its Consumers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

To my understanding, React's Context *Provider* updates its *Consumers* whenever the *context value* changes.

[From the Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider):

> All consumers that are descendants of a Provider will re-render
>   whenever the Provider’s `value` prop changes. The propagation from
>   Provider to its descendant consumers is not subject to the
>   `shouldComponentUpdate` method, so the consumer is updated even when an
>   ancestor component bails out of the update.
>
> Changes are determined by comparing the new and old values using the
>   same algorithm as [Object.is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is#Description).

However, the following code seems to indicate the opposite:

```js
var themes = {
  light: {
    name: "Light",
    foreground: "#000000",
    background: "#eeeeee"
  },
  dark: {
    name: "Dark",
    foreground: "#ffffff",
    background: "#222222"
  }
};

const ThemeContext = React.createContext({
  theme: themes.light,
  updateTheme: () => {}
});

let prevTheme = undefined;

function App() {

  console.log("RE-RENDERING App...");
  const stateArray = React.useState(themes.light);

  const [theme, setTheme] = stateArray;

  const [otherState, setOtherState] = React.useState(true);

  function handleSetOtherState() {
    console.log("SETTING OTHER STATE.....");
    setOtherState(prevState => !prevState);
  }

  console.log("theme:", theme);
  console.log("prevTheme:", prevTheme);
  console.log(`Object.is(prevTheme, theme): ${Object.is(prevTheme, theme)}`);
  prevTheme = theme;
  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={stateArray}>
      <Toolbar />
      <button onClick={handleSetOtherState}>Change OtherState</button>
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
}

class Toolbar extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    console.log("RE-RENDERING Toolbar (DOES NOT HAPPEN WHEN CHANGING OTHERSTATE)...");
    return (
      <div>
        <ThemedButton />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function ThemedButton() {

  console.log("RE-RENDERING ThemedButton (SHOULD NOT HAPPEN WHEN CHANGING OTHERSTATE)...");
  const themeContext = React.useContext(ThemeContext);
  const [theme, setTheme] = themeContext;
  console.log("themeContext:", themeContext);
  console.log("theme.name:", theme.name);
  console.log("setTheme:", setTheme);

  function handleToggleTheme() {
    console.log("SETTING THEME STATE.....");
    setTheme(
      prevState =>
        themes.dark
    );
  }

  return <button onClick={handleToggleTheme}>Click me: {theme.name}</button>;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

As seen, when clicking `Change OtherState`:

1. The parent component enclosing the context `Provider` will re-render, thus allowing the `Provider` to see that there has indeed **not** been **any** change to the *context value*
2. The children will re-render because their parent did, but that process is stopped mid-ways in the process by `Toolbox` being a `PureComponent`
3. Now, the whole idea of the context `Provider`, is that it should **only** update its `Consumers` if the *context value* changed
4. The change check is done with `Object.is`, as specified in the Docs (see above)
5. Regardless of that fact, the `Consumer` (`ThemedButton`) still updates when `OtherState` changes
6. That should not happen, because the *context value* did in fact **not** change, and the child re-rendering is stopped in the middle with `PureComponent`
7. Only when the *context value* changes should the `Consumers` update, even if the re-rendering is stopped in intermediate components with `PureComponent`

PS: You can see that *context value* does not change when `Change OtherState` is clicked, by looking at the `Object.is` console log.

**Question**

Why does `ThemedButton` re-render, when the *context value* did not change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useState` returns a new array every call. So you pass a new array to context every render.
[useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) to fix the issue.

```js
var themes = {
  light: {
    name: "Light",
    foreground: "#000000",
    background: "#eeeeee"
  },
  dark: {
    name: "Dark",
    foreground: "#ffffff",
    background: "#222222"
  }
};

const ThemeContext = React.createContext({
  theme: themes.light,
  updateTheme: () => {}
});

let prevTheme = undefined;
let prevStateArray = undefined;

function App() {

  console.log("RE-RENDERING App...");
  const stateArray = React.useState(themes.light);
  console.log('stateArray', prevStateArray, stateArray, Object.is(prevStateArray, stateArray));
  prevStateArray = stateArray;

  const [theme, setTheme] = stateArray;
  const memoState = React.useMemo(() => [theme, setTheme], [theme, setTheme]);

  const [otherState, setOtherState] = React.useState(true);

  function handleSetOtherState() {
    console.log("SETTING OTHER STATE.....");
    setOtherState(prevState => !prevState);
  }

  console.log("theme:", theme);
  console.log("prevTheme:", prevTheme);
  console.log(`Object.is(prevTheme, theme): ${Object.is(prevTheme, theme)}`);
  prevTheme = theme;
  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={memoState}>
      <Toolbar />
      <button onClick={handleSetOtherState}>Change OtherState</button>
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
}

class Toolbar extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    console.log("RE-RENDERING Toolbar (DOES NOT HAPPEN WHEN CHANGING OTHERSTATE)...");
    return (
      <div>
        <ThemedButton />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function ThemedButton() {

  console.log("RE-RENDERING ThemedButton (SHOULD NOT HAPPEN WHEN CHANGING OTHERSTATE)...");
  const themeContext = React.useContext(ThemeContext);
  const [theme, setTheme] = themeContext;
  console.log("themeContext:", themeContext);
  console.log("theme.name:", theme.name);
  console.log("setTheme:", setTheme);

  function handleToggleTheme() {
    console.log("SETTING THEME STATE.....");
    setTheme(
      prevState =>
        themes.dark
    );
  }

  return <button onClick={handleToggleTheme}>Click me: {theme.name}</button>;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. Is that the most common / typical way to ensure consumers only update on changed context (assuming we want to give the consumers the ability to update the context themselves)?

Comment: Quick follow-up: Does the function inside useMemo (first arg) only run if dependencies change? I got confused by the docs, which say: "Remember that the function passed to useMemo runs during rendering" - Source: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo.

Comment: It depends on the value passed to `Context.Provider`. With two separate contexts for `theme` and `setTheme` you don't need to use `useMemo` because `setTheme` is guaranteed to be the same function every render.
Callback passed to `useMemo` doesn't run every render. But when it does it happens during rendering.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies it. By the way, I think I came up with a better way to do it. Basically, i just put my state-updating-function inside state itself. Because, the state object will not change on re-render. That way, I do not need useMemo. See my example code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/7jv99l7okj